# данные не сохраняются при обновлении бота. heroku

Tags: python, heroku, discord

Я создал бота на python, и выставил на хостинг heroku. Но при обновлении бота у него все данные загружаются с GitHub. Можно как-то загрузить базы данных бота с сервера heroku к себе на компьютер, потом обновить бота и заменить базы данных на сервере heroku. Чтоб не терялись данные при обновлении бота. На самом деле у меня не базы данных, а обычные текстовые документы вместо них)

Comment: Дайте вопросу нормальное название, плиз.

Comment: Я почти ничего не понял из вопроса, но подозреваю, что ещё один не читал документацию Heroku и не знает про эфемерную файловую систему.